# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' when access through a webhosted service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the following issue when i m trying to access the wcf service through WcfTestClient. The service is hosted on an Hostgator site

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at INotifyService.saveNotifyEmail(NotifyBE notifyEntity)
at NotifyServiceClient.saveNotifyEmail(NotifyBE notifyEntity)

Inner Exception:
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Config file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="WeddingNirvana.DataAccess" value="WeddingNirvana.DataAccess"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">

          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Could anyone help me with what the issue is.

I have tried using the answers that were already in stackoverflow but all of them are related to the Certificate, which i have not applied

Comment: When you hit the same WCF url with a web browser, are you able to connect and see the WSDL?  Are you prompted for a login or any authentication?

Comment: @tgolisch i am not getting any prompt for login and it is opening as it would normally

Comment: This error message means you did not authenticate.  Usually this means you need to use a login/pw, or you have an authentication certificate. Usually, the web browser will prompt you to choose a cert, but your app will not.  So, there is no authentication for your WCF?  I noticed that part was missing from your config (above).

Comment: No haven't set any authentication this is the whole config file that i have

Comment: You don't have a config section for your system.servicemodel\client\endpoint.  Without it, I'm not sure how your program will know which URL to go to.  Do you set that in code or another config or something?

Comment: issue resolved. was some service detail that was not activated on the server